# Attempt to uninstall java on Mac failed

Tags: java, java-8

I am willing to run Spark shell on my machine, which is incompatible with my version (java 11), so need to remove and install compatible version (jdk8). Run following commands as specified by [oracle](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml):

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

Commands run, but still java 11 present:

```
$ java -version
java version "11" 2018-09-25
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

Not sure what causes this.

Comment: make sure the JDK configured on the PATH is updated and you really won't need to remove 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't remove JRE or JDK. If you need to locate all your Java installations just launch the following command:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (6):
    11.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    10.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_40, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_11, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_37-b06-434, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_37-b06-434, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home
```